# How can I add cron jobs in docker image

Tags: python, docker, cron

```
FROM python:3.10.2

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron curl


EXPOSE 8084

COPY . .

CMD ["flask", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

just a function to test

```
@crontab.job(minute='*')
def writeones():
    with open('t.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write("Now the file has more content!")
```

But after command docker-compose up
I type flask crontab add and its output:

```
no crontab for root
```

Comment: Do you really need cron inside a container? You could instead use cron with docker run commands from the host OS

Comment: Yes. How i can use it inside docker